# Is ndb.put_multi atomic?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, atomic, app-engine-ndb

I have a list of entities to put for instance. One of them is not valid. I call `ndb.put_multi(entities_to_put)`.

Should it put some of them in the list and then throw error, or should it not put any of them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put_multi` will either succeed of fail for all entities being put.  The implmentation of `put_multi` is essentially just a loop over the entities which calls `put` on each one; there is no exception handling to isolate individual failures.

This code demonstrates the behaviour:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):

    bar = ndb.IntegerProperty()

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        # Trigger an exception during save.
        if self.bar > 10:
            raise ValueError('%d is too big' % self.bar)

# Clear any existing foos
existing = Foo.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
ndb.delete_multi(existing)

# Instantiate new foos
vals = [0, 1, 20, 3, 4]
foos = [Foo(bar=val) for val in vals]

# Save new foos
try:
    ndb.put_multi(foos)
except ValueError as ex:
    print 'Exception raised during save: %s' % ex

saved_foos = Foo.query().fetch()
print 'Saved foos:', saved_foos

# Output
Exception raised during save: 20 is too big
Saved foos: []
```